# Remotely Access WD MyCloud EX2 Using Finder

Tags: network, finder, hard-drive, nas

We recently purchased a WD MyCloud EX2 NAS storage drive in my office. On our local network, we're able to use Finder>Go>Connect To Server, mount the drive, and access files simply through finder. This is all good, but we would like to access this remotely as well. We have the option to do this, but we are forced to download WD's software, and I was hoping there was some way to accomplish this simply through finder like when we're on the local network.

I'm not super network-saavy, but could this be accomplished with port forwarding or something of that nature? Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your router needs to forward the required ports to your NAS.

AFP: 548, 427
SMB: 445

Then you can connect to your NAS the same way you do now, but you'll have to use your EXTERNAL IP. If your external IP is dynamic (regularly changing), I'd recommend using a service like dyndns (which keeps track of your IP and binds it to a domain).

Comment: I tried to mount the drive the the same way but get a pop up that server can't be accessed...what's the file path you used? Are you on Yosemite? A lot more people around the community boards are asking too.. you are the only one saying it can be done.

Comment: Hello, I have set up port-forwarding so that I can "talk" to the EX2. This means that I can do ssh to the EX2 from outside of my local network. To do that I use a public IP that is kept up-to-date (I hope) on no-ip.org. Still I cannot do AFP and SMB because my router is a Apple Time Capsule, which is apparently taking the AFP and SMB ports for its use. Any suggestions to work around this?

Comment: ...using a non-standard port seems to do the trick...